# Fixed Navbar broke unrolling menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am helping on this website: www.noyoco.com.
I recently added a script to fix the nav bar on top when user scrolls.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $("#main-nav");
    var pos = s.position();     
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("stick");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick"); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

But I can't figure out why unrolling menu is broken.

Working properly when on top (script is off), broken when script is on (if you have scroll)

Can someone help with that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the fact that the second menu is not in absolute position of the nav container. It's only in `display: block;` and `display: none;` when you toggle it with the main menu.

To fix that, you can add a relative position on the parent container like this :

```
.multi-level-nav {
  position: relative;
}
```

And an absolute position to the menu on the submenu :

```
.tier-2 { 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2; /* to be above the slideshow */
}
```

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**

It's also because of this selector, you have to change it because of the change of the structure when it becomes `fixed`  :

```
.nav-row ul ul {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for helping!
I added those in my style sheet and rebuild my script like that:
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $("#main-nav");
    var pos = s.position();  
    var blop = $(".nav-row ul ul");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("stick");
           blop.css("display", "none");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick"); 
        }
    });
});
</script>

But it is not working.
Did I do wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's better to use a class for the sub menu, so you are perfectly **sure** to target the right one instead of the `.nav-row ul ul` who can target other thing if you change the structure

Comment: Hey Vincent, thanks for helping.
Actually the solution was pretty simple, I just had to use another Jquery selector in my script:  var s = $("#main-nav .multi-level-nav")
That works correctly now!

Comment: Yes because the selector `.nav-row ul ul` was working good with that one instead of the parent one #main-nav who was hiding the wrong level of submenu :)